# Как unserialize данные?

Tags: php, unserialize

Данные на сервер приходят в виде такой строки:

```
sport[]=1&music[]=0&web[]=2
```

Как это рассеализировать в php?

вариант

```
$data = unserialize($post["data"]);
```

Почему-то вызывает ошибку:

```
ErrorException [ 8 ]: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 27 bytes ~ APPPATH\classes\controller\ajax.php [ 14 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не сериализованный массив! [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) вам в помощь.

Comment: мне на stackoverflow тоже так ответили.